# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php

I have made an sms handler system, and everything is okey, working fine.
But I get this error: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
Its in the 17. line $user is the 17. line, I know its just notice, but daily 20-30 "notice" is in my php error log, and I wanted to fix this.

I tryed many different method, but no changes.
Somebody can help to fix it? Thanks!

```
$conn           = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
$id             = $_GET["id"];
$from           = $_GET["from"];
$to             = $_GET["to"];
$msg            = explode(" ", $_GET['message']);
$user           = substr(trim($msg[1]),0,10);
```

Comment: What does `$msg` look like? Does it really have spaces in it? What is in `$msg[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing this code helps less to understand but still i would recommend you to place

```
if(isset($msg[1]) && $msg[1] != ''){
  $user = substr(trim($msg[1]),0,10);
} else {
  $user = '';
}
```

because it looks like in some cases $msg[1] does not exist. For example if `$_GET['message'] = 'Hello';`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$_GET['message']` does not seem to contain a second element. Are you sure its set?

Your code should handle this nicely by having an if or sthg similar. Examples:

```
$user = "anonymous";
if (sizeof($msg)) > 1) {
  $user = substr(trim($msg[1]),0,10);
}
```